# Determining if projections and reflections are orthogonal

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

A linear transformation $T$ is a projection if $T^2 = T$, and $T$ is a reflection if $T^2 = I$.

1. I have $T(x,y) = (-x -2y, y)$. I have already shown that $T$ is a reflection, but I also need to determine if $T$ is orthogonal, and I'm not sure how.
2. I have $T(x,y) = (x+y,0)$. I know it's a projection but, again, I need to determine if $T$ is orthogonal and I'm not sure how.

My intuition was to dot product $T(x,y)$ with $T(a,b)$ and verify if it's equal to $0$.

Answer (score 2):

Guide:

A transformation is [orthogonal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_transformation) if $\langle u, v\rangle = \langle Tu, Tv\rangle$.

In finite-dimensional spaces, the matrix representation (with respect to an orthonormal basis) of an orthogonal transformation is an orthogonal matrix. Its rows are mutually orthogonal vectors with unit norm, so that the rows constitute an orthonormal basis of $V$. The columns of the matrix form another orthonormal basis of $V$.

$$T(x,y) = \begin{bmatrix} -1 & -2 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} x \\ y\end{bmatrix}=Ax$$

You just have to verify if $A^TA=I$, if it is, then it is orthogonal.

Comment: Wouldn’t it be easier to just calculate the inner product?

Comment: Sure if it is easy for you. but perhaps one can just look at the matrix and conclude without doing any further computation too.

Comment: It’s just that at this point in my linear algebra course we’re not supposed to use matrices. By the way, it appears from intuition that most transformations will turn out as not orthogonal..

Comment: yup, they are not orthogonal. hmmm... ok, then verify directly then. you can just construct counter example to prove that they are not orthogonal.

Comment: @VictorS. There are a _lot_ of transformations that are, though.

Comment: Perhaps what is meant here (at least in $2$) is to verify whether $T$ is an orthogonal projection, i.e. $T^2 = T = T^T$. Orthogonal projections are never orthogonal in the sense $T^TT = I$, unless $T = I$.